# Understanding list indexing errors

Tags: python, list, indexing

Say I have a list:

```
a = ['what','now','what','now','what','now']
```

Now if I do:

```
for x in range(2, len(a)):
    if a[x:x+1] == a[x-2:x-1]:
        print True
```

I get `True, True, True, True`

Now if I do :

```
for x in range(2, len(a)):
    if a[x] == a[x-2] and a[x+1] == a[x-1]:
        print True
```

I get `True, True, True, Traceback (most recent call last):..IndexError: list index out of range`

Shouldn't the two produce equivalent results? What is happening here?

Comment: Slices are allowed to go beyond the end of a list, but straight indexes are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the 2nd one, you're doing `x+1` which happens to be 6.

Here is how you can see it in the future:

```
for x in range(2, len(a)):
    try:
        if a[x] == a[x-2] and a[x+1] == a[x-1]:
            print True
    except Exception, e:
        print x
```

to fix the problem, you can do

```
for x in range(2, len(a)-1):
    try:
        if a[x] == a[x-2] and a[x+1] == a[x-1]:
            print True
    except Exception, e:
        print x
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example a[x:x+1] doesn't include len(a) + 1.
In the second example a[x+1] is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an index that is way outside a list for slicing:

```
>>> a = ['what','now','what','now','what','now']
>>> a[3:100]
['now', 'what', 'now']
```

Here it as the same effect as `a[3:]`.

But you will get an index error when you access an index outside the range of a list:

```
>>> a[100]
IndexError: list index out of range
```